# Can I reset the cookies which are set from site minder agent?

Tags: single-sign-on, siteminder

I have application where I am using SSO ( site minder agent) 
UserID is set in the cookies. I want to reset this UserID which is saved in cookies. I am unable to do this? Is this possible? If yes how can this be achieved?

Comment: What do you mean by "reset"? What are you trying to do? Log in as a new user? Or impersonate another user (like a help desk app?)?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should not be setting the user id in the cookie. The user name is always available to the application in the form of the SM_USER header.

To kill the cookie you need to set the cookie header in the http response and set the expiry date of the cookie to a time earlier than current time